How to implement localization in livewire SPA app?
In laravel 11 / livewire 3.5 app I want to localize 3 pages and I created my own middleware app/Http/Middleware/SetLocaleMiddleware.php:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Livewire\Attributes\On;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

/* Class set locale middleware by 'locale' session var */
class SetLocaleMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)  $next
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        // I see these lines in log - so this middleware works ok
        \Log::info(varDump(session()->get('locale'), ' -1 OUT SetLocaleMiddleware session()->get(locale)::'));
        if (session()->has('locale')) {
            \Log::info(varDump(session()->get('locale'), ' -1 INSIDE SetLocaleMiddleware session()->get(locale)::'));
            App::setLocale(session()->get('locale'));
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}

I added it to bootstrap/app.php :
return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        web: __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php',
        api: __DIR__.'/../routes/api.php',
        commands: __DIR__.'/../routes/console.php',
        health: '/up',
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        $middleware->appendToGroup('web', SetLocaleMiddleware::class);
    })
    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
        //
    })->create();

I switch locale in livewire component method as :
#[On('localeChanged')]
public function localeChanged(string $locale) {
    $this->locale = $locale;
    session()->put('locale', $this->locale);
    App::setLocale($this->locale);
    $this->dispatch('$refresh');
}

But locale is not changed.
Reading manual  https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/upgrading#localization I modified routes/web.php:
Route::group(['prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale()], function ()
{
    
    Route::get('/services/partnership-order/{locale?}', PartnershipOrderDialog::class)->name('services.partnership_order.index');
    Route::get('/services/pricing/{locale?}', Pricing::class)->name('services.pricing.index');
    Route::get('/{locale?}', QuizChooser::Class)->name('home');
    
});

But I did not catch what is class LaravelLocalization here ? I does not look like SetLocaleMiddleware (it has no setLocale method).
PS. Loooking at some localization examples I see that localizationis made with calling separate controller method and returning back.
As I make SPA app I would prefer to implement localization without separate controller, but do not know can I do it ?
